# Fundamental Limit on Antenna Gain?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, gain, wave, electromagnetic

Harold A. Wheeler, “Fundamental Limitations of Small Antennas,” has introduced the concept of **"boundary sphere"**, where the smallest sphere or circle surrounding an antenna has interesting implications in path loss equations.

Hans Gregory Schantz from Q-Track Corporation has calculated the maximum gain for an electrically small antenna.

[image]

Source: http://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pister/290Q/Papers/Antennas%20propagation%20interference/near%20field%20path%20loss.pdf

The formula I have marked with green, turns out that since the law of conservation of energy, and because 1 antenna can't be inside the other antenna's boundary sphere, he has derived this equation, where the gain of an electrically small antenna has to be smaller or equal than this.

#### Well it turns out this is formula is derived from the path loss equations:

$$k=\frac{2*\pi }{\lambda} $$
$$d=distance\hspace{0.3cm}between\hspace{0.3cm}the\hspace{0.3cm}antennas (meters)$$

- Friis formula for farfield Planewave
  $$PathLoss_P=\frac{G_t * G_r }{4}* (\frac{1}{(kd)^2})$$
- Schantz formula for nearfield E-field
  $$PathLoss_E=\frac{G_t * G_r }{4}* (\frac{1}{(kd)^2}-\frac{1}{(kd)^4}+\frac{1}{(kd)^6})$$
- Schantz formula for nearfield H-field
  $$PathLoss_H=\frac{G_t * G_r }{4}* (\frac{1}{(kd)^2}+\frac{1}{(kd)^4})$$

Specifically the formula above is derived from the E-field pathloss equation introduced also by Schantz in another paper, the coefficients are the same basically. **He used "R" to denote the radius of the boundary sphere, we will use "d" to denote the diameter.**

### Does this mean that we can logically deduce the maximum gain of a nearfield magnetic antenna or an antenna in the far field to be the following, based on the this logic:

$$k=\frac{2*\pi }{\lambda} $$
$$d=diameter\hspace{0.3cm}of\hspace{0.3cm}boundary\hspace{0.3cm}sphere$$

$${Gain_P}_{max}=\sqrt{ \frac{4}{(\frac{1}{(kd)^2})} } $$
$${Gain_E}_{max}=\sqrt{ \frac{4}{(\frac{1}{(kd)^2}-\frac{1}{(kd)^4}+\frac{1}{(kd)^6})} } $$
$${Gain_H}_{max}=\sqrt{ \frac{4}{(\frac{1}{(kd)^2}+\frac{1}{(kd)^4})}} $$

## Would this be a logical deduction? I would love to hear professional engineer's comment on this.

Comment: I've used this approximation: take the antenna maximum length, convert into a square, and examine how much of a wavelength^2 is covered. That is your (fractional) gain approximation. Thus an antenna with 0.01 wavelength as max size would have 0.01 * 0.01 or -40dB gain, as approximation. The plot in OP says to expect -25dB.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the data comes from Hans Gregory Schantz's research, it should be accurate.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf actually, this is the fundamental limit on antenna gain, so if my plot says -25 dB that would constitute for the maximum gain that is theoretically possible (practically probably not). If your approximation is accurate, your's is probably a sort of median gain for your average situation, but that doesn't mean that the gain can't exceed that under special conditions.